# What happend to too localized?

Tags: discussion

Looking at flagging or closing questions, "Too Localized" seems to have disappeared. Was this done on purpose? Seems like a perfectly good reason if someone asks something not terribly useful to others

Comment: That was part of the close vote system revamp that was supposed to make it better, but really has had no effect whatsoever.

Comment: @MattYoung: Are very localized questions now acceptable?

Comment: No, we didn't change our standards. This was a SE wide close vote revamp. We just have to make a reason for the close vote in the off topic menu. Once one person makes a off topic reason, others can follow.

Comment: +1.  I miss `too localized` too.  I've voted to close some of the questions as `off-topic -> other: "too localized"`.

Comment: They removed too localized because they did not intend it to be used for anything except very very focused questions and we, as well as others, were overusing it.

Comment: It was removed as part of the PC overhaul of the close system.  They decided that the morons that can't be bothered to read the rules or care about them if they do are more important than those providing answers here.  It is part of the overall effort to hasten the demise of this site by chasing away experts so that only the clueless will be left writing drivel to each other.

Answer (score 5):

The reasoning behind the changes to close votes was explained in detail on the [Stack 
Overflow Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/) and on [Meta.Stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons-bye-bye).  The short reason was that the old close reasons were seen as overly hostile by many new users.

[image]